# Como crear un Web Services con C# y utilizando SSDT (SSIS)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, webservice, ssis, visual-studio-2019

A lo que me refiero es, quiero realizar sitio web con C#, donde el usuario pueda cargar un archivo excel, y utilizando SSDT (ETL) pueda verificar los datos del archivo cargarlo a la base de datos. 
No se si se pueda, y si no, conocen otra manera de subir archivo excel por una web y este que lo cargue a la base de datos?

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Tiene codigos ó metodos que ha probado para resolver esta problema? Por favor agregalo en la pregunta.

Comment: como pregunta, que quieres almacenar en la BD el archivo o su estructura y datos?